# Underline text with Docusaurus markdown syntax

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

I'm developing a website using Docusaurus version 2, and would like to underline text. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no markdown way to add underline…

You need to use the `HTML` tag `u` or `isn`:

```
# Your title

Start of the paragraph, <u>with an underlined text</u>. 
<isn>This text is also underlined.</isn>
```